# SpringBootTest exclude packages from being scanned

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I want to exclude some packages from being scanned when using spring `@SpringBootTest` in the same way it is done with `@ComponentScan`.
Is there something like

```
@SpringBootTest(excludeFilters =@ComponentScan.Filter(
            type = FilterType.REGEX,
            pattern = "package\\.\\.to\\.Exclude.*"))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that the best workaround on this is to create a class annotated with the `@SpringBootApplication` and configure the scanning configuration there

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses ={TestConfiguration.class})
public class TestApp {
}
```

Then your unit test you should specify the test class created previously

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestApp.class)
public class UnitTestClass {
}
```

Comment: High time for @SpringBootTest to contain exclude classess